# Can’t boot after updating libllvm and libdrm

Tags: 18.04, logout

After logging out of my current session my screen is stuck like this: [image]

I recently upgrade my libdrm and libllvm as well as running flatpak update. When trying to launch some games, they crashed saying something about LLVM, and that the hw limit was 0:0. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and this just happened.

**UPDATE**: After restarting my computer and trying things such as recovery mode and repairing my Python3 symlinks, the computer now doesn’t finish booting with status “started hold until boot process finishes up.”